# mongoDB text index on subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that looks something like this

```
{ "text1" : "text", 
  "url" : "http:....", 
  "title" : "the title",
   ......, 
   "search_metadata" : { "tags" : [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ],
                         "title" : "the title",
                         "topcis": [ "topic1", "topic2"]
                       } 
}
```

I want to be able to add a text index to `search_metadata` and all it's subdocuments.
`ensureIndex({search_metadata:"text"})` Gives me no results
and:
`ensureIndex({"$**":"text"})` will give me irrelevant data

How can I make it happen?

Answer (score 3):

From the [text indexes page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/):

> text indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array
>   of string elements. To perform queries that access the text index, use
>   the $text query operator

Your `search_metadata` field is a series of sub-documents, not a string or an array of strings, so it basically is not in the right format to make use of a text index in MongoDB as it is currently structured.

Now, embedded in `search_metadata` you have both strings and arrays of strings, so you could use a text index  on those, so an index on `{search_metadata.tags : "text"}` for example fits the criteria and should work just fine.

Hence, it's a choice between restructuring the field to meet the text index criteria, or a matter of indexing the relevant sub-fields.  If you take the latter approach you may find that you don't need text indexes on each of the fields and a simpler (and far smaller) index may serve you just as well (using a normal index on tags and then [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for example).